# Normalisation of a two column data using min and max values

Tags: r, normalization, max, min

I am trying to find an R code for normalisation of my values using min and max value for a two column matrix.

My matrix looks like this: Column one (C1) and C2 I.D not to be calculated,
C3; Heading row 1 then 407 numbers and NA´s, C4;heading row 1 then numbers and NA´s.

I was thinking of something like:

Min value for C3 = x, Max value for same column x,

```
If(x="","NA",(x-Min value)/(Max value-Min value))
```

This would give a column with values from 0 to 1. 
The same should be done for column 4 (would that be y or is this confusing for R?)

I am not skilled enough in programming or in R to generate this code, is there a specific code for this or can anyone help me write one?

Comment: Why should there be any `""` in the matrix? Your description says that there are numbers or `NA`s in `C3` and `C4`. Please clarify and whilst you are at it, edit your Q to include the output from `head(foo)` where `foo` is the name of your matrix object (which I presume is actually a data frame).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Given some example data along the lines you describe

```
set.seed(1)
d <- data.frame(C1 = LETTERS[1:4], C2 = letters[1:4],
                C3 = runif(4, min = 0, max = 10),
                C4 = runif(4, min = 0, max = 10))
d
```

then we can write a simple function to do the normalisation you describe

```
normalise <- function(x, na.rm = TRUE) {
    ranx <- range(x, na.rm = na.rm)
    (x - ranx[1]) / diff(ranx)
}
```

This can be applied to the data in a number of ways, but here I use `apply()`:

```
apply(d[, 3:4], 2, normalise)
```

which gives

```
R> apply(d[, 3:4], 2, normalise)
            C3        C4
[1,] 0.0000000 0.0000000
[2,] 0.1658867 0.9377039
[3,] 0.4782093 1.0000000
[4,] 1.0000000 0.6179273
```

To add these to the existing data, we could do:

```
d2 <- data.frame(d, apply(d[, 3:4], 2, normalise))
d2
```

Which gives:

```
R> d2
  C1 C2       C3       C4      C3.1      C4.1
1  A  a 2.655087 2.016819 0.0000000 0.0000000
2  B  b 3.721239 8.983897 0.1658867 0.9377039
3  C  c 5.728534 9.446753 0.4782093 1.0000000
4  D  d 9.082078 6.607978 1.0000000 0.6179273
```

Now you mentioned that your data include `NA` and we must handle that. You may have noticed that I set the `na.rm` argument to `TRUE` in the `normalise()` function. This means it will work even in the presence of `NA`:

```
d3 <- d
d3[c(1,3), c(3,4)] <- NA ## set some NA
d3


R> d3
  C1 C2       C3       C4
1  A  a       NA       NA
2  B  b 3.721239 8.983897
3  C  c       NA       NA
4  D  d 9.082078 6.607978
```

With `normalise()` we still get some output that is of use, using only the non-`NA` data:

```
R> apply(d3[, 3:4], 2, normalise)
     C3 C4
[1,] NA NA
[2,]  0  1
[3,] NA NA
[4,]  1  0
```

If we had not done this in writing `normalise()`, then the output would look something like this (`na.rm = FALSE` is the default for `range()` and other similar functions!)

```
R> apply(d3[, 3:4], 2, normalise, na.rm = FALSE)
     C3 C4
[1,] NA NA
[2,] NA NA
[3,] NA NA
[4,] NA NA
```

Comment: I guess I used "" when doing the normalisation in excel. There are numbers and NA´s in the columns. Regarding names "matrix", data frame I am a little confused and I see now when looking in R that you are right -you seem to know what you are doing :). I will try this -It works :D x a lot for your quick and straight forward awnser.

Comment: @Kicki Thanks. Do consider Accepting Answers you get to your Questions. See the [ask] section of the FAQ on why this is useful. To Accept an Answer, check the big tick mark next to Answer you wish to Accept.

Comment: Oh more to learn :) Thank you for bringing this to my attention!

Answer (score 0):

This is a type of non-parametric normalisation, but I would advise you to use another method: calculate the median and interquartile range, subtract the median and divide by the IQR. This will give you a distribution with median 0 and IQR 1.

```
m <- median( df$C3, na.rm = T )
iqr <- IQR( df$C3, na.rm = T )
df$C3 <- ( df$C3 - m ) / iqr
```

The method that you propose is extremely sensitive to outliers. If you really want to do it, this is how:

```
 rng <- range( df$C3, na.rm = T )
 df$C3 <- ( df$C3 - rng[1] ) / ( rng[2] - rng[1] )
```

Comment: Where did I go wrong, I get this strange message:Error in df$C3 : "object of type 'closure' is not subsettable"? Otherwise your suggestion sounds interesting. Will try again. As I said I am a new bee in this world of programming and R. Thank you a lot for answering my question :)