# Scale dataset in R

Tags: r, time-series, beta-distribution

I have 528 observed of temperature data the range value of data (2-53). I was to scaled the data to make it range between 0 and 1 to fit beta distribution to find weather the beta distribution is fit the data or not.

Can anyone tell me please how can I make scaled to my data?

Comment: You mean data normalisation to range [0,1], right? Check this : http://stn.spotfire.com/spotfire_client_help/norm/norm_scale_between_0_and_1.htm and also some great answers here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12969623/normalisation-of-a-two-column-data-using-min-and-max-values

Answer (score 0):

Divide them by the biggest value... e.g.

```
# Dummy data
x = rnorm(100, mean=15)

# Normalise
x = x/max(x)
```