# min max scaling/normalization in r for train and test data

Tags: r

I am looking to create a function that takes in the training set and the testing set as its arguments, min-max scales/normalizes and returns the training set and uses those **same** values of minimum and range to min-max scale/normalize and return the test set.

So far this is the function I have come up with:

```
min_max_scaling <- function(train, test){

  min_vals <- sapply(train, min)
  range1 <- sapply(train, function(x) diff(range(x)))

  # scale the training data

  train_scaled <- data.frame(matrix(nrow = nrow(train), ncol = ncol(train)))

  for(i in seq_len(ncol(train))){
    column <- (train[,i] - min_vals[i])/range1[i]
    train_scaled[i] <- column
  }

  colnames(train_scaled) <- colnames(train)

  # scale the testing data using the min and range of the train data

  test_scaled <- data.frame(matrix(nrow = nrow(test), ncol = ncol(test)))

  for(i in seq_len(ncol(test))){
    column <- (test[,i] - min_vals[i])/range1[i]
    test_scaled[i] <- column
  }

  colnames(test_scaled) <- colnames(test)

  return(list(train = train_scaled, test = test_scaled))
}
```

The definition of min max scaling is similar to this question asked earlier on SO - [Normalisation of a two column data using min and max values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12969623/normalisation-of-a-two-column-data-using-min-and-max-values)

My questions are:
 1. Is there a way to vectorize the two `for` loops in the function? e.g. using `sapply()`
 2. Are there any packages that allow us to do what we are looking to do here?

Answer (score 34):

Here is the code for the min-max normalization. See this [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Feature_scaling#Rescaling_(min-max_normalization)) for the formulae, and also other ways of performing feature scaling.

```
normalize <- function(x, na.rm = TRUE) {
    return((x- min(x)) /(max(x)-min(x)))
}
```

To get a vector, use `apply` instead of `lapply`.

```r
as.data.frame(apply(df$name, normalize))
```

---

Update to address [Holger](https://stackoverflow.com/users/590437/holger-brandl)'s suggestion.

If you want to pass additional arguments to `min()` and `max()`, e.g., `na.rm`, then you can use:

```r
normalize <- function(x, ...) {
    return((x - min(x, ...)) /(max(x, ...) - min(x, ...)))
}

x <- c(1, NA, 2, 3)

normalize(a)
# [1] NA NA NA NA

normalize(a, na.rm = TRUE)
# 0.0  NA 0.5 1.0
```

Just keep in mind, that whatever you pass to `min()` via the ellipsis `...` you also implicitly pass to `max()`. In this case, this shouldn't be a big problem since both `min()` and `max()` share the same function signature.

Comment: I'd like the answer even more if it could expose the na.rm argument used by min and max to handle NA

Answer (score 14):

Regarding your 2nd question, you can use the `caret` package:

```
library(caret)

train = data.frame(a = 1:3, b = 10:12)
test = data.frame(a = 1:6, b = 7:12)

pp = preProcess(train, method = "range")


predict(pp, train)

#     a   b
# 1 0.0 0.0
# 2 0.5 0.5
# 3 1.0 1.0

predict(pp, test)

#     a    b
# 1 0.0 -1.5
# 2 0.5 -1.0
# 3 1.0 -0.5
# 4 1.5  0.0
# 5 2.0  0.5
# 6 2.5  1.0
```

This packages also defines other transformation methods, see: http://machinelearningmastery.com/pre-process-your-dataset-in-r/

Answer (score 0):

```
    set.seed(1984)

### simulating a data set 

df <- data.frame(var1 = rnorm(100,5,3), 
                 var2 = rpois(100,15), 
                 var3 = runif(50,90,100))

df_train <- df[1:60,]
df_test <- df[61:100,]



## the function 

normalize_data <- function(train_set, test_set)  ## the args are the two sets

{ 
  ranges <- sapply(train_set, function(x) max(x)-min(x)) ## range calculation

  normalized_train <- train_set/ranges   # the normalization
  normalized_test <- test_set/ranges

  return(list(ranges = ranges,                    # returning a list 
              normalized_train= normalized_train,
              normalized_test =normalized_test ))
  }


z <- normalize_data(df_train, df_test)   ## applying the function 

    ## the results 
    z$ranges
         var1      var2      var3 
    13.051448 22.000000  9.945934 
    > head(z$normalized_train)
             var1      var2     var3
    1  0.47715854 1.1492978 7.289028
    2  0.18322387 0.4545455 4.280883
    3  0.69451066 1.3070668 9.703761
    4 -0.04125108 1.6090169 7.277882
    5  0.35731555 0.7272727 4.133561
    6  0.86120315 0.6032616 9.246209
    > head(z$normalized_train)
             var1      var2     var3
    1  0.47715854 1.1492978 7.289028
    2  0.18322387 0.4545455 4.280883
    3  0.69451066 1.3070668 9.703761
    4 -0.04125108 1.6090169 7.277882
    5  0.35731555 0.7272727 4.133561
    6  0.86120315 0.6032616 9.246209
```

Comment: Thank you for the attempt to answer but I am looking at a way to scale by data by subtracting the minimum of that column from every row and then dividing by the range. Your answer does not take the subtraction of minimum into account.