# Scale data with caret package in R to [-1 1] range

Tags: r, scale, r-caret

Is there any way to scale data to the range [-1 1] using `caret` package in R, or the only solution is to use functions such as [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/9478/how-to-normalize-data-to-let-each-feature-lie-between-1-1)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [min max scaling/normalization in r for train and test data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44050028/min-max-scaling-normalization-in-r-for-train-and-test-data)

Comment: I seek a caret solution only if possible, in your reference by applying "range" method it returns a scaled series of range [0,1]

Comment: I use `scale()` from package `scales`.

Comment: I prefer to use caret as it gives me the ability to scale multiple features simultaneously and also use the same scalers to the test dataset. Check below my answer if it works as well.

Answer (score 1):

Consult with `caret` package (suffice to say that I did **not** RTFM), I came across with the `rangeBounds` parameter that comes along with "range" `method` to scale the data with the desired range.

Try the below:

```
Scaler <- caret::preProcess(Data, rangeBounds = c(-1,1),method = "range")
ScaledData = predict(Scaler,Data)
```